# changing style to that of hover using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the styling of the list item that holds my link on click, so the style of that `<li>` changes to that of the hover style. But adding `$(this).addClass('hover');` doesn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$('a.app1-preview').click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('hover');
                    //do other things now:
            $('.app-preview-2').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $('.app-preview-1').fadeIn("slow");

            });        
        });
```

My HTML code is:

```
    <div class="app-container">
                    <ul class="apps">
                      <li class="app1"> 
                          <a title href="#" class="app1-preview blocklink">
                                <span>ANOTHER<br /> APP</span>
                          </a> 
                      </li>
</ul></div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.app-container ul.apps li.app1 { border-color:#57b6dd; background:url(app-icons/app1.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; position:relative; }
.app-container ul.apps li.app1:hover { background:#57b6dd url(app-icons/app1-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; color: #fff; border-color:#57b6dd;}
.app-container ul.apps li.app1 a { color: #57b6dd; }
.app-container ul.apps li.app1-inactive { border-color:#b2b2b2; background:url(app-icons/app1-inactive.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; position:relative; }
.app-container ul.apps li.app1-inactive:hover { background:#b2b2b2 url(app-icons/app1-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; color: #fff; border-color:#b2b2b2;}
.app-container ul.apps li.app1-inactive a { color: #b2b2b2; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setting `hover` class to your `a` tag instead of your `li` element.

So try this:

```
$('a.app1-preview').click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
                    //do other things now:
            $('.app-preview-2').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $('.app-preview-1').fadeIn("slow");

            });        
        });
```

And you should add, if not already exists, a hover class named `hover` to your css declarations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no class named `hover` in your css, so make it like this instead:

```
.hover { 
    background:#b2b2b2 url(app-icons/app1-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; 
    color: #fff; 
    border-color:#b2b2b2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

:hover works only on the mouse over. adding a class hover wont assign the :hover class to the element.

the alternative way could be to change the :hover to .hover

Answer (score 1):

Add a second CSS selector to your hover CSS:

```
.app-container ul.apps li.app1:hover,
.app-container ul.apps li.app1-hover
{
    background:#57b6dd url(app-icons/app1-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 10px; 
    color: #fff; 
    border-color:#57b6dd;
}
```

Now do where you need it:

```
$(this).addClass('app1-hover');
```

You'll get the same styling as your hover and you'll also preserve your hover CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hover class in your css. Add a class hover & then add it using jquery. Add this to your css:

```
a.app1-preview.hover { 
 background:#57b6dd url(app-icons/app1-hover.png) no-repeat 10px 10px;
 color: #fff; border-color:#57b6dd;
}
```

demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kKX86/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trigger `mouseenter` on the element, and have the style displayed:

```
$('a.app1-preview').click(function() {
                    $(this).trigger('mouseenter');
                    //do other things now:
            $('.app-preview-2').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $('.app-preview-1').fadeIn("slow");

            });        
        });
```